# What is the difference between JupyterLab and JupyterHub?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

What is the difference between `JupyterLab` and `JupyterHub`? How should I decide which one to deploy for users?

Answer (score 31):

JupyterHub is encapsulated environments for multiple users.

JupyterLab is a new version (for the lack of better words) of Jupyter Notebook. It is notebook, text editor and python console together with a file explorer.

Jupyter Notebook plugins may not work with JupyterLab (which is currently beta now).

If you want to use Jupyter Notebook, just use Jupyter Notebook.

If you want multiple users to juse their own Jupyter Notebooks encapsulated in the same machine, Jupyter Hub.

If you want to play with beta software, Jupyter Lab.

Comment: You can also launch JupyterLab for users from within JupyterHub!

Comment: And there is Jupyter Enterprise Gateway, for running kernel on remote machines.